# Sonar Installation problem

Tags: sonarqube

Information about Installation

Using embedded database Derbis

Problem :

I run `bin/windows-x86-32/StartSonar.bat`  and then click http://localhost:9000

On clicking this, I get the following error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
Please try back in a few minutes and contact support if the problem persists.
<%= link_to "Go back to the homepage", home_path %>
```

Do you know what to do with that error message.

Answer (score 6):

I usually get that message when the database isn't correctly set (either the local has an issue, in which case I try a fresh installation).
Or the mysql database you can associate has an issue (wrong '`sonar.jdbc.username`' or '`sonar.jdbc.password`' in `sonar.properties` file.).
Or the default port for the embedded database (`jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sonar;create=true`) isn't available on your server/workstation.

---

If you are using a Mysql database (not your case), you need to create it first:

```
mysql [localhost] {root} ((none)) > CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sonar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql [localhost] {root} ((none)) > grant all privileges on sonar.* to 'sonar'@'localhost' identified by 'sonar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql [localhost] {root} ((none)) > flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

---

Q4 2023, [Purval Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6777663/purval-patel) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791051/sonar-installation-problem/4791495?noredirect=1#comment136977623_4791495) to his blog post:

"[SonarQube installation Ubuntu](https://impurval.blogspot.com/p/sonarqube-installation-ubuntu.html)"

Comment: make sure that the user name and password fit to what it says in the sonar config file.

Comment: https://impurval.blogspot.com/p/sonarqube-installation-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 3):

http://localhost:9000/setup will initialize the database and correct this error

Answer (score 3):

Check the sonar log file for finding the issue you are facing. find out the error form the log file and try to solve it.

cheers..!

Answer (score 2):

My OS is `Mac`.

If the version of sonar is `6.x`, please try to run the follow steps:

1. Check the log: `/Users/test/Downloads/sonarqube-6.0/logs/sonar.log`
2. Whether it have the ERROR: `“zh-CN” is not a valid locale` or `“en” is not a valid locale`
3. Please run the command: `gem uninstall -i /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0 i18n`

The version of Ruby is your default ruby.