# get nothing after installing Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

Information about installation using MYSQL:

I run `bin/windows-x86-32/StartSonar.bat` and click `http://localhost:9000`.
On clicking this, I get nothing.

Then I `echo errorlevel = %errorlevel%` and I found `errorlevel = 1`.

I googled this problem but I found nothing useful.

Do you guys know what to do with that error?

Comment: Have you looked for logs that might tell you about some unhappiness?

Comment: Agree check the Sonar log file located in the "logs" directory. Additionally give Sonar some time to startup. First time round it needs to create the database schema and initialise everything

Answer (score 18):

- What OS are you running on?
- do you have Java 32bit or 64 bit installed?
- in the logs directory of Sonar it should be changing size everytime you try to start it, if it is not, perhaps the process does not have permissions on that file?
- were you able to make it work with the default db before trying to see if the app could run via MYSQL?

---

I had to make a few changes to get it running locally on my win7 64bit.

- I changed the settings in `/conf/wrapper.conf`

  - commenting out the line `wrapper.console.loglevel=NONE`
  - so I didn't have to go back and forth reading the log file, or trimming it.
- I changed the `.bat` file's starting lines to

  ```
  rem @echo off
  setlocal
  java -version
  ```
- In `/conf/sonar.properties`

  ```
  sonar.web.host: 127.0.0.1
  sonar.web.port: 9000
  sonar.web.context: /
  ```

then started the batch file. it takes quite awhile to initialize the first time.

**Also on Win2008 as a service I had to**

- `/conf/wrapper.conf`

add `wrapper.java.additional.3=-Djava.io.tmpdir=../../temp/`

since access was denied to `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp`
- [reference](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2660)

---

then I could finally see the website on localhost:9000

Lots of hoops after that for sonar-runner, and gallio

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791051/sonar-installation-problem)

Comment: It was the temp dir that did it for me.

Comment: The reference claims that the bug has been solved a long time ago - but it is still an issue with SonarQube 4.5.1.

With 4.5.1 wrapper.java.additional.3 needs to be wrapper.java.additional.2 since there is no .2 and no gaps are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Following articles may help you to configure sonar properly.

For installing sonarqube [here](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/10/sonarqube-tutorial)

For configure sonar plugin with eclipse [here](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/10/eclipse-sonar-tutorial)